# Using UIPageViewController without storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to add a tutorial to my app using `UIPageViewController`, but my app is not using **storyboard**, do you know any tutorial that could explain to me how to do it? I've been looking around but everything mention **storyboard**.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why this question is closed? I had the same issue, and the question was a solution for me.

Comment: Agree.  This question is NOT off topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good one (without storyboards):

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

Comment: The first one looks good indeed, I'll try this.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, pleas check it as correct.

Comment: @dasdom on second hand, don't bother, the question will probably get closed anyway. #anachronism

Comment: Is there a swift example?